# Pop Up with JQuery Created Links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I have a word cloud that is created by JQuery. Each word in the cloud will highlight red when you hover over it and each word is a link to a URL. What I would like to have is each link come up in a pop up. Here is an example of what I would like the pop up to look like: http://www.cybernetiksolutions.com/popup/popup.jpg . I have found a few script that allow you to do pop ups using JQuery but not when the link is being created via JQuery as well. Can someone point me in the right direction on this.

Here is a link to the work that I have already done on this project. http://www.cybernetiksolutions.com/popup/index.html

Answer (score 1):

> I have found a few script that allow you to do pop ups using JQuery but not when the link is being created via JQuery as well.

Those are probably the simple `$(selector).click(function() { ... });` handlers you have seen. The reason those don't work with newly created elements is that they only scan the DOM for elements that match the selector when that function is ran, most probably on document ready. ( `$(document).ready(function(){ /* right here */});` )

You have two options for attaching event handlers to the links you are creating.

1. Attach the event handler when the link is created
2. Use event delegation by using jQuery's [**delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (v1.4.3+) or [**on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (v1.7+) functions

**Option 1 (attaching after creation):**

After adding all the elements:

```
$('#wordcloud').find('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default click action
    //do your popup magic right here
});
```

**Option 2: delegation**

Anywhere, on document ready:

Using [**.delegate**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('#wordcloud').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default click action
    //do your popup magic right here
});
```

Using [**.on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#wordcloud').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default click action
    //do your popup magic right here
});
```